# How can I place a page link to the sidebar admin bar?

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar

Im trying to create a function that place my page link http://mypage.com/mypage in the Admin Sidebar, not in the top Admin Bar like the code bellow does know.

```
function toolbar_link_to_my_page( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'my-page',
        'title' => 'My Page',
        'href'  => 'http://mypage.com/mypage',
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-personal-page' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_my_page', 999 );
```

Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added custom menu link by following. Hope it will be helpful.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'custom_admin_menu_new_items' );
function custom_admin_menu_new_items() {
    global $menu;
    add_menu_page( 'My Page', 'My Page', 'manage_options', 'my-page', '','', 6 );
    foreach($menu as $mIndex => $mData) {
        if($mData[2] == 'my-page') {
            $menu[$mIndex][2] = 'http://mypage.com/mypage';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Action hook `admin_menu` is used. New menu is added by `add_menu_page`. And after that URL of the menu is overridden by checking the slug in the foreach loop.